# how to send date as timestamp in svelte?

Tags: javascript, html, svelte

The svelte application is supposed to send these data to create an event to be stored in a database.

```
let eventName=document.querySelector('#eventName')
    let timeFrom=document.querySelector('#timeFrom')
    let timeTo=document.querySelector('#timeTo')
    let repeatedEvery=document.querySelector('#repeatedEvery')
    let startFrom=document.querySelector('#startFrom')
    let endOn=document.querySelector('#endOn')
    const status="upcoming"
    let isRepeated=true
```

The dates should be sent as UNIX timestamps, I can do that just fine. The problem is to do that I had to add `toString()` to the variables which gives me an error of "this element is null", without it gives me 5 overload errors. I tried declaring the variable in a function that would do this process but the variables are not global anymore.

I don't want to fix the current code, I'll write the whole thing from scratch if I have to, my question is how do I actually approach this in the first place?
the dates input fields are datetime-local, and needless to say the timestamps should be a number, all the other types of data go through just fine.

Comment: You should not query the DOM when using Svelte. Use `bind:...` to get values of DOM elements, and `bind:this` to get the element itself, though this should rarely be necessary.

Comment: @H.B. that's what I did in the html, bind:value and tied them to the variables above

Comment: Then why are you using a ton of `querySelector`?

Comment: because I have to declare values, if I don't it'll give me an error "[variable name] is probably undeclared" and it won't render because of it

Comment: That is *not* how to deal with that error.

Answer (score 1):

[Date.prototype.valueOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) returns what you need.

```js
const dNow = new Date();
dNow.valueOf(); // 1673445066359
```

If you are getting `null` values in variables that are supose to be Dates, you can default them to a value.

```js
const dDateDefaultToNow = theSourceValueThatYouAreUsing || new Date();
const dDateDefaultToZero = theSourceValueThatYouAreUsing || 0;
```

This way, if `theSourceValueThatYouAreUsing` is `null` then it will default to `new Date()` or `0`.

For more help, please share more of your code.

Comment: This solution works if I wanna get the current date, what I'm trying to do is turn user entered dates to timestamps, I already have bind:value used and connected from the HTML inputs to the variables. I need to figure out how to turn this input to timestamps